# SQL Left Join with verification on each table

Tags: sql, postgresql, request, left-join

First, my SQL skils are really bad.
Here is my tables :

```
Message :
id | title | arrayusers
1  |Title1 | a:2:{i:1;i:1;i:5;i:5;}
2  |Title2 | a:2:{i:1;i:1;i:5;i:5;}
3  |Title3 | a:2:{i:1;i:1;i:5;i:5;}
4  |Title4 | a:2:{i:1;i:1;i:5;i:5;}
5  |Title5 | a:2:{i:1;i:1;i:5;i:5;}
6  |Title6 | a:2:{i:1;i:1;i:5;i:5;}

Read :
id | status | userid | message_id
1  |   0    |   5    |    1
2  |   0    |   1    |    2
3  |   0    |   5    |    2
4  |   0    |   1    |    3
5  |   0    |   5    |    4
6  |   1    |   1    |    5
7  |   1    |   5    |    5
7  |   1    |   5    |    6
```

I use the userid 1 for my test :

My goal, is to get all lines from `Message`, where my user 1 is in `arrayusers` with a LIKE(i:1;i:1;)

And user 1 not in table `Read` (userid), with the `status` equal to 0. If another user (5) but not me (user 1) is in `Read` table, I want to see my `Message` line

With the data above, I want to return the id 1 / 4 from `Message` table

I started a request with Left join, but my request hide line id 1 and 4 because there is another user in this table with this id.

```
SELECT * FROM message as m
LEFT JOIN read as r ON m.id = r.message_id
WHERE m.arrayusers LIKE '%i:1;i:1;%'
AND r.id IS NULL
```

Hope you understand my request.
Someone can help me to debug my request ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't like arrays in tables. Is there any reason why you didn't make this a separate table? And `a:2:{i:1;i:1;i:5;i:5;}` means user 1 sent the message and user 5 received it? But why then is there a record for message 2 user 1 in table `read`? To indicate that user 1 hasn't read their own message? I am sure you would benefit from a more relational data model.

Comment: You say you want to see messages 1 and 4. But that should be 1, 4, 5, and 6, because for none of these there is a record for user 1 with status 0 in the `read` table. So far you are contradicting yourself. Please clarify.

Comment: `{i:1;i:1;i:5;i:5;}` mean, the message is in destination to user 1 and 5. The data model isn't from me, I can't change it, I don't like the array field too... yes i made a mistake about the result, I want 1 / 4 / 5 / 6, you right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `NOT EXISTS`or `NOT IN` to look up the status in the `read` table:

```
select * 
from message
where arrayusers like '%i:1;i:1;%'
and id not in
(
  select message_id
  from read
  where userid = 1
  and status = 0
);
```

As to your own query: You are merely missing the criteria on the `read` table:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message as m
LEFT JOIN read as r ON m.id = r.message_id and r.userid = 1 and r.status = 0
WHERE m.arrayusers LIKE '%i:1;i:1;%'
AND r.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I have a question about your request. How can I get the `read` table data in addition to data already get ? Because I got `NULL` value in each field of table `read` but some fields aren't empty. Thanks

Comment: You are looking for messages for which no `read` record exists, so how can you expect any `read` values? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

What is the use of `AND r.id IS NULL`? Please remove this condition and check:

```css
SELECT * FROM message as m
LEFT JOIN read as r ON m.id = r.message_id
WHERE m.arrayusers LIKE '%i:1;i:1;%'
AND r.id IS NULL
```

Comment: The use of `AND r.id IS NULL` is to create an anti-join (i.e. find all `message` records that have no match in `read`). It's a method used in DBMS that have issues with the straight-forward `NOT EXISTS` / `NOT IN`.